# 403 forbidden with socket.io and iisnode

Tags: node.js, iis, https, socket.io, iisnode

I have a node.js socket.io server application that I have just moved to IISNode in IIS 8.5 in Windows Server 2012. It is set up to use https.

It all works fine when I browse locally but when I try to access it with a full domain name, I get error 403 (forbidden) when I try to open the web socket connection.

The same problem happens with my real application as happens with the Dante Devine Comedy socket.io sample. [Tomasz Janczuk iisnode Dante sample](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/01/hosting-socketio-websocket-apps-in-iis.html)

The standard sample when browsed to with

```
https://localhost/dante/server-socketio.js
```

or with

```
https://interfaces.xxxxxx.co.uk/enable/testing/dante/server-socketio.js
```

locally on the same server, opens the socket.io web socket connection with

```
var client = io.connect('https://localhost', { resource: 'dante/socket.io' });
```

and works correctly producing the following network capture:

[image: Working network capture]

Obviously the above does not work when accessed externally (not localhost) so I change the web socket connection to

```
var client = io.connect('https://interfaces.xxxxxx.co.uk/enable/testing', 
              { resource: 'dante/socket.io' });
```

and this fails with an error 403 as follows:

[image]

my web.config is the same as the one supplied with the Dante sample and contains:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="iisnode-socketio" path="server-socketio.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>

<rewrite>
     <rules>
          <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
               <match url="socket.io"/>
               <action type="Rewrite" url="server-socketio.js"/>
          </rule>
     </rules>
</rewrite>    

<webSocket enabled="false" />
```

I'm new to node.js, socket.io and iisnode and a bit of a novice with IIS so this could be a simple iis/web site/https problem and not related to iisnode.

I'd appreciate it if anyone has any suggestions.

John.

---

Following CuriousGuy's suggestion, I now get the following network capture showing that the switch to web socket protocol has not happened. The actual error shown is

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://interfaces.xxxxxx.co.uk/enable/testing/dante/socket.io/1/websocket/ANNcSf7ghQp66nwSS-7P' 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

[image: No longer gives 403 error]

I tried changing the server io.set from

```
io.set('resource', '/dante/socket.io');
```

to

```
io.set('resource', '/enable/testing/dante/socket.io');
```

but that was clearly a mistake because I then get an error that io is undefined which seems a little weird.

If I examine the network traffic in fiddler I see:

[image: output from fiddler]

and the following error message in fiddler when I tap the last network line:

iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

```
HRESULT: 0x6d
HTTP status: 500
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because
system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled 
configuration setting is 'true'.
```

The server stderr log shows:

```
debug: served static content /socket.io.js
debug: client authorized
info: handshake authorized o7WE52TfMWPxFoJIZFJJ
debug: setting request GET /dante/socket.io/1/websocket/o7WE52TfMWPxFoJIZFJJ
debug: set heartbeat interval for client o7WE52TfMWPxFoJIZFJJ
warn: websocket connection invalid
info: transport end (undefined)
debug: set close timeout for client o7WE52TfMWPxFoJIZFJJ
debug: cleared close timeout for client o7WE52TfMWPxFoJIZFJJ
debug: cleared heartbeat interval for client o7WE52TfMWPxFoJIZFJJ
```

Comment: Try to replace `io.connect('https://interfaces.xxxxxx.co.uk/enable/testing', {resource: 'dante/socket.io'});` with `io.connect('https://interfaces.xxxxxx.co.uk', {resource: 'enable/testing/dante/socket.io'});`. Is it working then?

Comment: Thank you very much for what is clearly a great suggestion. This definitely gets rid of the 403 error but it now doesn't successfully upgrade to websocket protocol. The server responds with 200 instead of 101 to switch protocols. I'll create another answer to the question so I can paste a new network capture.

Comment: You can edit an existing post. Just click "edit" in the bottom left of this question

Comment: Sorry, yes you're right that would have been better than adding another answer.

Comment: To tidy things up, I'll move the text of my answer to the original question...

Comment: You may try to turn off your firewall and antivirus (if any). Sometimes websocket errors occur because of these two

Comment: Also try using XHR polling instead of WebSockets. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9570373/2600208) may be useful

Comment: I suppose this error occurs because of your version of Socket.IO (0.9.*) is not compatible with current version of Chrome. I have one idea how to fix it. Can you join the chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55665/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-atkinsonline).